# invoking the iframe from another window

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a link which pass a source to an iframe:

```
<a href='new.mp4' target='showVideo'></a>
<iframe src='sample.jpg' name='showVideo' ></iframe>
```

What I want to do is have the link `<a>` point to a PHP file and would return a new source for the `<iframe>`. this means that the file of my PHP is different from where my `<iframe>` is located:

Sample of what i want to accomplish;

sample.html:

```
<a href='sample.php''></a>
<iframe src='sample.jpg' name='showVideo' ></iframe>
```

sample.php:

```
<?php
  //Code that will get a variable in MySQL
  echo "<a href='".$somePhpVariable."' target='showVideo'></a>";
?>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Point your `<a>`'s `target` to the frame, and in the PHP file, use `header("Location: ...")` to then redirect the frame to the desired URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't rename your sample.html to PHP, you can try an AJAX call. Here's an example idea using JQuery (testing need):

sample.php:

```
<?php
  //Code that will get a variable in MySQL
  echo $somePhpVariable;
?>
```

sample.html:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function updateIframe() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "sample.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#myiframe').attr('src', data);
    });
}

</script>

<a href='javascript:;' onclick='updateIframe()'></a>
<iframe id="myiframe" src='sample.jpg' name='showVideo'></iframe>
```

This will call sample.php using AJAX and will change the iframe src with the server value.